# In function hook_block_view, what is the use of '#theme'

Tags: blocks

In function hook_block_view, what is the use of `#theme`.
As we code :

```
<?php 
function hook_block_view($delta = '') { 
 $block = array();
 switch ($delta) { 
   case 'syndicate':
   $block['subject'] = t('Syndicate'); 
   $block['content'] = array( 
       '#theme' => 'feed_icon', 
       '#url' => 'rss.xml',
       '#title' => t('Syndicate'),
   );
   break;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an element with the `#theme` property set is rendered, it invokes the `theme()` function, with all other properties on the element (i.e. all except `#theme`) as arguments.

So your example:

```
$block['content'] = array( 
  '#theme' => 'feed_icon', 
  '#url' => 'rss.xml',
  '#title' => t('Syndicate'),
);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$block['content'] = theme('feed_icon', array(
  'url' => 'rss.xml', 
  'title' => t('Syndicate'),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `$block['content']` with that array is like using the following code.

```
$block['content'] = theme('feed_icon', array('url' => 'rss.xml', 'title' => t('Syndicate')));
```

`#theme` is followed by the theme name, and each index that would be passed in the `$variable` array to the theme function are prefixed with a `#` and used in the array together `#theme`.

The usage of `#theme` is shortly described in [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7), where you can read:

> HTML generation for a renderable array, and the treatment of any children, is controlled by two properties containing theme functions, #theme and #theme_wrappers.

Its usage is not limited to `hook_block_view()` but it can be used in every place Drupal expects also a render array being returned from a hook or another function, such as a page callback.